# Is there a way to get the contrast default color / font color of a theme in md-colors directive or in javascript?

Tags: angularjs, colors, material-design, contrast

I want to get the color used to contrast the theme to apply to a border so that it follows the font color and changes accordingly if the theme colors are changed.

Something like, if the theme makes the font color white, I'd need to get this white color.

I just can't find the value for the md-colors directive to get the contrast color.

I already try something like

```html
<div md-colors="{border-color: primary-contrast}" style="border-right: 1px solid">
```

or

```html
md-colors="{border-color: primary-foreground}"
```

or

```html
md-colors="{border-color: foreground}"
```

or

```html
md-colors="{border-color: foreground-1}"
```

But none of this works.

When the palette is define there is a "contrastDefaultColor" so there has to be a way to get the contrast color for a palette in the md-colors directive or directly in javascript. Something like this "primary-hue-1-contrast" to get the contrast color of the primary hue 1 color.

Answer (score 0):

[See Documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.6/api/directive/mdColors#theme-palette-hue-opacity)

```
[?theme]-[palette]-[?hue]-[?opacity]
 [theme] - default value is the default theme
 [palette] - can be either palette name or primary/accent/warn/background 
 [hue] - default is 500 (hue-x can be used with primary/accent/warn/background)
```

Example:

```
 <div md-colors="{background: 'myTheme-accent-900-0.43'}">
  <div md-colors="{color: 'red-A100', 'border-color': 'primary-600'}">
   <span>Color demo</span>
  </div>
 </div>
```